# number of frames recorded by AudioRecorder

Tags: android, audio

i am using AudioRecorder to record sound for exactly 300 milliseconds. For that, i used `TimerTask` and `scheduleAtFixedRate` to stop the recording after 300 milliseconds.
But when i check the output files, the length is varying from a file to another by an offset equal to `4096`, it is always constant(+/-), and when i checked i found out that its the `frameCount*2`. So, is that because the non precision of threads? if so, what does a frameCount corresponds to in seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audio I/O APIs like processing things in sizes like 4096 (a power of 2). If the file sizes are always 4096, best guess is that it's the minimum frame granularity guaranteed by API, though this might not be explicitly documented.

If you *really* need only 300 ms of audio, then you might need to do some manual postprocessing in order to chop off those extra samples.

Comment: Thank you Mike. Actually, that is what happened, i had to cut it off manually.

Comment: i want to know, each 2048 frame is per second?

Comment: 2048 frames is way too few to fill a second. Common sampling rates should be 44100 Hz and 48000 Hz, which would indicate 44100 or 48000 frames per second.

Comment: hmm this is weird. 44100 samples in 1 second. then for 200 ms i should have 8820 pcm samples. in my case i get 20480  bytes (20Ko).